# For loop not maintaining order through iterations (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, pyspark, iteration

Supposedly, a for loop should always [maintain order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086774/does-the-for-in-loop-construct-preserve-order) through iterations; however, I am running a for loop in python where it is supposed to iterate over a list with 276 elements (text strings), and up until element 139 the resuls are in the same order as the initial list, but from thereof they are apparently randomly ordered.

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

EDIT:

The original list to loop over was obtained from a pyspark dataframe using the following code:

```
final_list = list(
df_redacted.select('id').toPandas()['id'])
```

The for loop is the following:(most of the imports are related to the function I am running inside the loop)

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import time
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from IPython.display import display
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
from datetime import timedelta

results = []
for x in final_list: 
    aux = df_complete.filter("id = '%s'" % x) 
    final= function(aux,"value") 
    results.append(final)
result
```

Comment: can you provide the example

Comment: We can't help you unless you share the relevant piece of code

Comment: probably something wrong with the way you constructed the list. So please try to construct a complete example (as simple as possible) that encapsulates the problem, and if that doesn't lead you to discovering the solution yourself, **edit** your question and add the code.

Comment: @Mureinik I think this is enough now?

Comment: @alexis is this enough or should I add something more?

Comment: not sure. but if you cannot include any data, at least add the imports. pyspark, you say? anything else? Also add the tag while you are at it, because the data source is _clearly_ the reason for your problem.

Comment: I dunno about pyspark, but the results of SELECT queries are usually not ordered in principle. So the results probably get into the list in semi-random order.

Comment: @alexis added, thank you! I'm sorry, I am very new at this and at the whole programming thing...
But it doesn't matter to me if the list is in the same order as the original dataframe; the only thing that would matter is that the for loop is iterating through the list correctly. That should not be influenced by the original dataframe, right? Since it was converted to a Pandas list

Comment: Looks good. I believe it would help to know how `df_redacted` was defined. But I don't know pyspark, so i'll wait for somebody else to chime in.

Comment: What you are trying to do here should have been done with a `join` operation of the two `df`s. Collecting into a python list and looping over it defeats the purpose of using Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for-look is iterating in fixed order. What must be happening is that the `select()` query is providing the results in non-deterministic order. You can confirm that for yourself by entering python interactively (or adding some diagnostic code), to print a "slice" of values from the part of the list that varies.

E.g.

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(final_list[139:150])
```

Execute this a few times and you will see that the for-loop just prints what is there.